# warning: simplexml_load_string()

Tags: magento-1.9

After I successfully installed the Theme in **magento 1.9** there is an **error** in

> system log warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 15: parser
>   error : Opening and ending tag mismatch in Update.php line 450

Answer (score 0):

check the xml files in the theme, mostly there is a missing closing tags, check them using a good IDE & it will show what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Open up `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php` and go down to line 450 where the error is occurring. Right before that line, insert a new line:

```
Mage::log(print_r($filename, true));
```

Make sure your logging is turned on, then refresh the page in your browser. It will end up spitting out a bunch of layout files in your var/log/system.log. The last layout xml file on the list should be your culprit. In my case, there were 4 spaces in front of the xml declaration in the last file on the list. So, I removed the spaces, and everything worked fine.

Don’t forget to remove the line you put in Update.php when you are done!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to some tag in layout (.xml) files of theme. You need to make sure that there should not a extra "<" or ">" in your files. sometimes when we write code

>

"extra > remain" in files.

Simplest way to find out cause is 
Use

Mage::log(print_r($filename, true));

in

this file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php

OR replace this line

$fileXml = simplexml_load_string($fileStr, $elementClass);

With

try {

$fileXml = simplexml_load_string($fileStr, $elementClass);

}
catch(Exception $e){

Mage::log(print_r($filename,null,"myerrorlog.log"));

}

Then open the myerrolog.log and get the name of erroneous xml file.